# Error: Call to undefined function SUM()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

using cakephp2

```
$total = $this->order->find('all', array(
    'fields'     => array(SUM(order.vat)),
    'conditions' => $condition
));
```

`SUM` function is not working for me, am geeting error:

> Call to undefined function SUM()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it like this,

```
$total = $this->order->find('all',array(
  'fields'=>array('SUM(order.vat) as total_vat'),
  'conditions'=>$condition
));
```

Add quotes around `SUM(order.vat)`.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Merchant

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

```
$this->order->virtualFields['total_vat']='SUM(order.vat)';

$total = $this->order->find('all',array(
  'fields'=>array('total_vat'),
  'conditions'=>$condition
));
```